# Every week I get System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have a program (C#) that communicate with embedded controller (Modbus), receiving data and log it to a data base. also, it shows the data in a user interface.

Every 5 or 8 days the program crashes (on every computer).

most of the time with no Exception and only the Windows default message "'program name' has stop working".

every once and a while I get the 'System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.' Exception.
The program, I'm assume is not designed well because the memory usage is increasing all the time.

After a week it reaches 800Mb.

Is this the problem?

I have tried reset the program every day. It didn't solve the problem.

This is the source:

```
namespace AtRegisterData
{
    public class RegisterDataManager
{
    modbus mb;

    public RegisterDataManager()
    {
        try
        {
            mb = new modbus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public static bool systemOnOffStatus = false;
    public static short systemOnOffState = 0;
    public static short reactorNum = 0;
    public int openCom(ReactorConfig reactorData)
    {
        try
        {
            if (mb.Open(Convert.ToString(ReactorConfigManager.ModBusConfiguration.com_port), Convert.ToInt32(ReactorConfigManager.ModBusConfiguration.ModBusBaudRate), 8, ReactorConfigManager.ModBusConfiguration.parity, ReactorConfigManager.ModBusConfiguration.stopBit))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;       // No connection
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeError(ex.Message);
            return 0; 
        }
    }
    public int CheckConnection(ReactorConfig reactorData)
    {
        try
        {
            // Needs to take the function data from public struct
            if (mb.Open("com20", 115200, 8, Parity.None, StopBits.One))
            {
                return 1;
            }

            // Needs to take the function data from public struct
            if (mb.Open("com1", 9600, 8, Parity.None, StopBits.One))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;       // No connection
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { writeError(ex.Message); 
            return 0; }
    }
    public List<ReactorEvent> getEvents(ReactorConfig reactorData)
    {
        try
        {
            ushort registerNum;
            List<ReactorEvent> eventsList = new List<ReactorEvent>();
            // List that will hold all of the data (all the registers)
            List<ushort> registerValues;
            // Get's the data from the modbus

            for (int i = 0; i < ReactorEventConfigManager.ReactorEvents.Count; i++)
            {
                registerNum = Convert.ToUInt16(ReactorEventConfigManager.ReactorEvents[i].ModBusRegisterNumber); // Convert the register numb to Unsigned short
                registerValues = new List<ushort>(); // Initlize the list
                try
                {
                    mb.SendFc3(reactorData.ModBusAddress, registerNum, 1, registerValues);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new NoConnectionException();
                    i = ReactorEventConfigManager.ReactorEvents.Count;
                }

                if (registerValues.Count > 0 && registerValues[0] == ReactorEventConfigManager.ReactorEvents[i].onFlag) // If the event is on?{eventsList.Add(ReactorEventConfigManager.ReactorEvents[i]);}
                {
                    eventsList.Add(ReactorEventConfigManager.ReactorEvents[i]);
                }
            }
            return eventsList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { writeError(ex.Message);
            return null; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from the controller
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reactorNumber">the reactor's ndbuumber</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Dictionary<Register, string> ReadData(ReactorConfig reactorData, List<short> unitedRegisters)
    {
        try
        {

            //Register tempRegister = new Register();
            Dictionary<Register, string> returnData = new Dictionary<Register, string>();
            string strRegisterValue;
            int registerLocation = 0;
            List<ushort> registerValues = new List<ushort>();                                         // List that will hold all of the data (all the registers)
            List<ushort> registerValuesNew = new List<ushort>();
            List<bool> coilsValues = new List<bool>();
            ushort startRegister, endRegister, midRegister;
            startRegister = endRegister = midRegister = 0;
            if (getStartAndEndReg(ref startRegister, ref endRegister, LoggerConfigManager.LoggerConfiguration.RegistersToLog) == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (endRegister >= 125)
                    {
                        midRegister = Convert.ToUInt16(endRegister - 124);
                        mb.SendFc3(reactorData.ModBusAddress, startRegister, 125, registerValues);   // Get's the data from the modbus
                        mb.SendFc3(reactorData.ModBusAddress, 125, midRegister, registerValuesNew);   // Get's the data from the modbus

                        if ((systemOnOffStatus == true) && (reactorNum == reactorData.Number))
                        {
                            shutdownLamp(reactorData, systemOnOffState);
                            systemOnOffStatus = false;
                        }

                        for (int t = 0; t <= registerValuesNew.Count - 1; t++)
                        {
                            registerValues.Add(registerValuesNew[t]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mb.SendFc3(reactorData.ModBusAddress, startRegister, endRegister, registerValues);   // Get's the data from the modbus
                        if ((systemOnOffStatus == true) && (reactorNum == reactorData.Number))
                        {
                            shutdownLamp(reactorData, systemOnOffState);
                            systemOnOffStatus = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    systemOnOffStatus = false;
                    writeError(ex.Message);
                    throw new NoConnectionException();

                }



                // This loop will organize all of the data received from the modbus in a dictionary
                for (int i = 0; i <= registerValues.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    registerLocation = findRegisterLocationInList(startRegister + i, LoggerConfigManager.LoggerConfiguration.RegistersToLog);   // Finds the register to copy by the register number
                    if (registerLocation != -1)
                    {
                        Register tempRegister = new Register();
                        copyRegisterData(tempRegister, LoggerConfigManager.LoggerConfiguration.RegistersToLog[registerLocation]);   // Copy the register Info
                        if (isRegisterInlist(tempRegister.RegisterNumber, unitedRegisters))                                         // Check if I need to unite to register to 1 4 byte variant
                        {
                            strRegisterValue = Convert.ToString(get4Byte(registerValues[i], registerValues[i + 1]));               // Unite 2 registers to 4 byte
                            i += 1;                                                                                                 // Need to skip the next register
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (tempRegister.DivideBy != null && tempRegister.DivideBy.HasValue)
                                strRegisterValue = Convert.ToString((double)registerValues[i] / tempRegister.DivideBy);
                            else
                                strRegisterValue = Convert.ToString(registerValues[i]);
                        }
                        returnData.Add(tempRegister, strRegisterValue);
                    }// Insert the data into dictionary
                }



                return returnData;
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeError(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: People can't help you without full code of your program..

Comment: Yes, running out of memory is likely to crash your program. Have you managed to work out what is using the memory?

Comment: I have added the source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the program for 5 - 8 days using a memory profiler like [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). This will give you a log of what was actually eating up your memory. Everything else is just guesswork.

Comment: Are there any free and/or open-source solutions?

Comment: I have the visual studio ultimate, does it contain a dotTrace alike compnent?

Comment: There seems to be [slimtune](https://code.google.com/p/slimtune/). But I worked woth both dotTrace and the one from RedGate and they are both worth the money, believe me!

Comment: http://memprofiler.com/download.aspx - Free, fully functional trial. Works nicely.

Comment: The dotTrace has 10 days trial. I will do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any source code I highly suspect you are not collecting garbage very well. You should always clean up after yourself in every method, ESPECIALLY in applications that run all the time. Always Dispose() of classes and other variables when done with them. Connections to SQL objects should be closed after data is exchanged. Any open files (IO) should be closed as well, and any external threads/processes called should be terminated.

If any of these are not done then your program will accumulate memory usage fast, and eventually collapse.

Comment: I have added the source

Comment: This seems to be only a fraction of the source, but I can already see quite a few memory leaks... To start with all those Open() methods are particularly concerning. I presume you are using a special device driver to communicate with whatever device runs with this program?

In windows, when you "open" a connection to a device you call an instance of the driver and load it into memory. I am guessing the device driver is a shared driver (or else the above code would have crashed much sooner) so that means every Open() command instantiates a new driver, and loads into memory...

Comment: To fix this, add a Close() method after each Open() when you are done with the connection (but before the return). This unloads that instance from memory. I am betting that is a huge portion of your memory leaks, you probably have hundreds of useless instances called up by the time it dumps the program ;). There's probably more memory leaks, as this is only a snippet, but hopefully I have given you enough information to clean it up significantly :).

Comment: Actually, I have close connection in every section I open connection. Except in the check connection. It's because Ineer use this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at all unmanaged ressources. If it is da DirectX app make sure you release all resources by hand. All Resources which are of type IDisposable should be disposed. Another starting point would be to check your Serializer, if you have a XmlSerializer for example.

I like the Red Gate Memory Profiler, there is a 14 day trial version available:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

So, after using dotTrace as suggested, I was able to find the memory leak.
It was in this function which called by  a timer:
    private void UpdateEventsScreen() 
        {

```
        int selectedRow = 0;
        try
        {

            if (EventsDataGrid.Rows.Count > 0)
                selectedRow = EventsDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            viewModel = new EventsViewModel();
            EventsViewModelSource.DataSource = viewModel;

            if (EventsDataGrid.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                EventsDataGrid.Rows[selectedRow].Selected = true;
                NoteValueLabel.Text = viewModel.Events[selectedRow].Note;
            }
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

I don't know why, but the line:

```
viewModel = new EventsViewModel();
```

cause the memory leak. I thought the garbage collector should handle this. Isn't it? 
Well, it didn't.

Thanks you all. You helped a lot.